# Uploading Android APK to google play store

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to upload a new version of our app (first time being exposed to android) and am dealing with this error when trying to upload the .aab file. I assume it means I don't have the original signing key file, I do not have access to it either, how can I get past this to upload?
[image]

Comment: Are you using a pipeline to do the build; i.e. the signing? Or are you building locally?

But you either need to get the original signing key or get a new one and configure it in the Google Play Console.

Comment: building locally

Comment: Like Malba said you're going to have to make a new key or find the original

Answer (score -1):

You should find the old version of app and keyStore file that was first uploaded with your previous update, if you create and upload new keystore google will always prompt with this error, i hope you find the old keystore file used for previous version update

Comment: I have the repository for the project, where would I find the keystone file?

Comment: you should ask the owner or whoever made and upload this project on playstore using key store file, it must be saved somewhere by someone who uploaded it first on playstore